# Set value to mocked object but get null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a simple class `Foo` to be mocked:

```
public class Foo {
   private String name;
   public Foo() {
   }
   public Foo(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
}
```

In my unit test code, I mock it by using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).

```
Foo mockedFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
mockedFoo.setName("test");
// name is null
String name = mockedFoo.getName();
```

I set `name` in mocked object, but when I call getter to get the name it returns **null**.

Is it a Mockito specific issue or is it an convention that mocked object can't set value? Why is that? What is happening underneath with mocked object?

Comment: `when(mockedFoo.getName()).thenReturn("test");`.

Comment: @Tom , I know this, but I want to know why I can not directly set value on mocked object, I am not asking how to stub function return.

Comment: Because it is a mocked object, and it's purpose is not to store stuff. Create your own instance if you want to do that.

Comment: @ Tom, so now you answered something I expected, so, it is a "convention" that mocked object looses the functions designed in the class.

Comment: Convention? I'd call it definition.

Comment: Yes, a mock just provides the same API, but no implementations. And that is why you use a mock. If you test class `A` (in a unit test), which uses `B` to store stuff in a file, then you want to mock `B`, so it doesn't actually perform "file stuff", because your main purpose is to test `A`, not `B`.

Comment: @Manu , that's why I added quotation marks around the word "convention". I know there will be someone argue about the word I am using.

Comment: @ Tom, thanks for the clearer comment answered my question.

Comment: @ Tom, I prefer your explanation, I feel it gives a knowledge about all mocked object in general, could you please make an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Leem.fin: But you should understand that this is specific to particular mocking frameworks. It's possible for a mocking framework to simulate trivial properties, and indeed some in .NET do exactly that. It looks like Mockito doesn't, but I wouldn't want to extend that to be too general.

Comment: @Leem.fin: Jons answer is already a good one, so it is a very good candidate to be accepted :).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well yes - the *actual* code of `Foo` doesn't matter, because you're mocking it... and Mockito doesn't know there's meant to be a relationship between `setName` and `getName`. It doesn't assume that it should store the argument to `setName` and return it when `getName` is called... it *could* do that, but it doesn't as far as I'm aware. The mock provided by Mockito just allows you to specify what happens when methods are called on it, and check what *was* called later on. Instead of calling `setName`, you could mock a call to `getName()` and specify what it should return...

... or you could just use `Foo` directly instead of mocking it. Don't think you have to mock *everything* in your tests. Just mock (or fake) things that are awkward when you're using the real class, e.g. because it uses the file system or network.

Comment: Indeed; from my experience, too often people mock "value-object" classes when they shouldn't. One thing I considered in the past was if it would be a good idea for a mocking library to detect such classes when a test attempts to mock them, and then throw an "invalid mocking" exception. Might be a good "opt-in" feature to add (and not too hard to implement).

Comment: but, we cannot mock a final method. How do we do in that case

Comment: @Sree: That's not what this question is about - I suggest you ask a new question if you can't find one which *does* match what you're asking. (I strongly suspect there are such questions though.)

Answer (score 20):

By default mockito has no behavior, on any methods in the mocked object.

You should do something like this:

```
Foo mockedFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
when(mockedFoo.getName()).thenReturn("someName");
String name = mockedFoo.getName();
```

edit: as mentioned by Jon Skeet, you should not need to mock things that can just be tested in a normal fashion.

Comment: what should we do to call the when() in our test?

Comment: `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;` should suffice. Then you might want to remove the `Mockito.` from the first line as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think, its better to understand as what *Mockito* does to your argument class and what kind of object it returns by referring to source code , [Mockito Source](https://github.com/mockito/mockito)

General understanding is that a mocked object is a fake object ( of same type as argument provided to `mock()` method ) with no real method implementations.So basically, nothing happens in real life for a method call on mocked object - and that is the very purpose of creating a mocked object ( that we don't wish to call real methods ) , isn't it?

We mock DAO layer, LDAP layer or other service dependencies because we don't want to invoke calls to actual DB or services. **If we want real calls to happen, we would not create mocked objects.**

Understanding to have something real have happened after calling `mockedFoo.setName("test");` OR `mockedFoo.getName();`  is incorrect - Nothing happens after you call a method on a mocked object and that is the purpose of mocked object which it is fulfilling.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem of knowing whether the setName() method was called in your code with the specified value use the Mockito verify method.

For example:

```
verify(mockedFoo, times(1)).setName("test");
```

Will verify that the mockedFoo.setName() method with the String parameter "test" was called exactly once in the code under test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call real methods on the mocked objects. use @Spy

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat this kind of approach is to used. I have written for EasyMock but with Mockito it can also be used as same.

```
String nameMock = createNiceMock(String.class);
Foo MockedFoo = new Foo();
Foo.setName(nameMock);

EasyMock.expect(Foo.getName()).andReturn(nameMock);
```