# How to Mock HttpSession and pass it as arguemnt to a method which works with session?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, httpsession

I am using Spring framework 2.4.4 and Intellij Ultimate 2020

I would like to test this method `tryGetUser` on which I am passing HttpSession, but I can't resolve the problem, because when I am mocking it and `setAttribute();` at the `//Arrange` part of the method it always ends with `currentUserUsername` to be null.

```
public User tryGetUser(HttpSession session) {
    String currentUserUsername = (String) session.getAttribute("currentUserUsername");
***// Here this local variable currentUsername is always null;***
    if (currentUserUsername == null) {
        throw new AuthorizationException("No logged in user.");
    }

    try {
        return userService.getByUsername(currentUserUsername);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationException("No logged in user.");
    }
}
```

Here you can see how I am trying to Mock it, but actually, the session is remaining empty or I don't know, but when the service method starts to execute the attribute is not there.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LoginServiceMvcTests {

    @Mock
    UserRepository mockUserRepository;

    @Mock
    UserService mockUserService;

    @InjectMocks
    MockHttpSession mockHttpSession;

    @InjectMocks
    LoginServiceMvc userService;

    private User junkie;
    private User organizer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        junkie = Helpers.createJunkie();
        organizer = Helpers.createOrganizer();
    }

    @Test
    public void tryGetUser_Should_GetUserFromSession_When_UserIsLogged() {

        // Arrange
        mockHttpSession.setAttribute("luboslav", junkie);
        Mockito.when(mockUserService.getByUsername("luboslav"))
                .thenReturn(junkie);

        // Act
        userService.tryGetUser(mockHttpSession);

        // Assert
        Mockito.verify(mockUserService, Mockito.times(1))
                .getByUsername("luboslav");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing authentication instead of using Spring Security?

Comment: I am not allowed to use it for this project. I have to learn it alone after this project. The reason which I was given by the mentor was it could break my project very easy hours before the defense of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Jon skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34205212/9959152) answer [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) doesn't work that way, so you need to actually mock the call instead of setting attribute

```
Mockito.when(mockHttpSession. getAttribute("currentUserUsername"))
            .thenReturn("name");
```

And also `HttpSession` should be annotated with `@Mock` not `@InjectMocks`

```
@Mock
HttpSession httpSession;
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and the solution. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MockHttpSession`, which is an actual real object (not just a Mockito interface mock) that is intended for exactly this type of testing. It's basically an empty/blank container, so you don't have to mock out all the standard behavior, just fill it with whatever attributes you want.